# Group template for list in sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, list, sencha-touch

I want to personalize the header group for a list.
First of all I have this function which concat n times a String :

```
String.prototype.times = function(n) {
  return Array.prototype.join.call({length:n+1}, this);
};
```

So I want to repeat n times an img html tag :

```
var list = new Ext.List(
{
   height : document.height - 150,
   itemTpl : "<div>blabla..</div>",
   store : listStore,
   groupTpl :[
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="x-list-group x-group-{id}">',
                '<h3 class="x-list-header">'+ '<img height="20" src="imgPath"/>'.times("{group}")+ '</h3>',
                '<div class="x-list-group-items">',
                '{items}',
                '</div>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ],
    grouped : true
 });
```

But it doesn't work at all, I think the "{group}" value isn't replaced for the javascript execution. But how can I handle that ?

Comment: I don't know if you got notified by SO about my edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it don't work as you expect because the template place holders are replaced later and when you do `'<img height="20" src="imgPath"/>'.times("{group}")` actually you are calling `String.prototype.times` with `"{group}"` as parameter, it will not work.

Second, I am not used to work with sencha-touch, I can offer a(ugly) work around, but you will far better of if some answer more "sencha-touch template" friendly comes up, the is the code:

```
function repeatImg(el, n){
    var newel = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        newel = el.cloneNode(false);
        newel.onload = null;
        el.parentNode.insertBefore(newel, el);
    }
    newel = null;
}
var list = new Ext.List(
{
   height : document.height - 150,
   itemTpl : "<div>blabla..</div>",
   store : listStore,
   groupTpl :[
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="x-list-group x-group-{id}">',
                '<h3 class="x-list-header">'+ '<img height="20" src="imgPath" onload="repeatImg(this, parseInt({group}, 10) - 1);"/>'+ '</h3>',
                '<div class="x-list-group-items">',
                '{items}',
                '</div>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ],
    grouped : true
});
```

This works if `{group}` is replaced by a number, didn't test for other values(like strings);

Edit: You could also have various images like 'img-0.png', 'img-1.png', ... , 'img-n.png' and use code like:

```
var list = new Ext.List(
{
   height : document.height - 150,
   itemTpl : "<div>blabla..</div>",
   store : listStore,
   groupTpl :[
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="x-list-group x-group-{id}">',
                '<h3 class="x-list-header">'+ '<img height="20" src="img-{group}.png" />'+ '</h3>',
                '<div class="x-list-group-items">',
                '{items}',
                '</div>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ],
    grouped : true
});
```

Comment: Ok it seems to be a good solution, I will have 5 different pictures but it not too much. Thanks for you're creativity ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot !! It works good. But I can't say that my problem is solved.

In fact I use the template group to display pictures of stars. For example if two items has one star, they are grouped. So in the header and thanks to "Prusse" we can see two juxtaposed pictures of star.

But, if we roll down the list, the pictures are disappearing when two headers of different groups are overlapping. I don't know how it works behind the group template but it seems the function "onload" is re-executed. (so the "groupTpl" property is evaluated for each roll on the list). Someone can tell me if there is a better way to do that ?

Comment: This is not a forum, please don't use answers as replies.  Use the comments on the answers or edit your original question.